# Javascript REGEX : Tags

Tags: javascript, regex, tags

**I want to convert words into tags.**

So for example I have an input, if I type in in this

`apple, windows, stackoverflow, google, microsoft`

then I will get this:

`apple`
`windows`
`stackoverflow`
`google`
`microsoft`

Delimiters should be **space**, **semicolon**, or **comma**, just like in stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`split` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split a string into an array, like this:

```
var tags = str.split(/\s*[ ,;]\s*/);
```

Comment: hmmmmm, looks cool, I've tested it here http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/ but why are there commas after each word? is it because of the array? and what are the `*` sry I'm new in regex

Comment: The `split` function returns an array.

Comment: The `*` means to match zero or more of the previous item.  `\s` means any (single) whitespace character.